# SPARQL different operator

Tags: sparql

#### SPARQL Query

I have some SPARQL query shown below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?name1 
    WHERE {

        GRAPH <blabla>
        {
            ?k swrc:author ?x .
            ?x foaf:name ?name1 . 
        } .

        GRAPH <blabla2>
        {   
            ?l swrc:author ?y .
            ?y foaf:name ?name2 .
        } .

        FILTER(?x != ?y) . 
    }
```

I want to get the names that exist only in the first graph `blabla`.

#### Problem

Counter intuitively I get some names that actually belong to the intersection. This happens because b (of set A) = b (of set B)?

#### Question

What are exactly the semantics of `!=` ? How can I surpass this problem?

Comment: A named graph is just a collection of triples.  It doesn't "own" the resources that appear in its triples.  RDF resources are either URIs, blank nodes, or literals.  A URI is the same no matter what graph it's appearing in.  That's actually one of the big _features_ of using URIs as identifiers.  It means that you can describe some resource, and so can someone else.

Comment: Given that URIs are identical regardless of where they appear, this seems like a duplicate of your earlier question [Set difference in SPARQL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21391444/1281433), modulo the fact that you're using a different patterns to bind variables.  It's still the same issue:  if you want a set difference `{?e : e in A, e not in B}`, you need a query like `...?e is an element of A... filter not exists { ...?e is an element of B... }`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The semantics of `!=` are exactly that its left argument is not equal to its right argument. But a FILTER is evaluated for every possible combination of values - so the query as you formulated it will return all name-values of `?x` for which *some* value of `?y` is not equal to it.

If you want to get back only name-values of `?x` for which *all* values of `?y` are not equal to it, you should be using a `NOT EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?name1 
WHERE {
 GRAPH <blabla>
 {
   ?k swrc:author ?x.
   ?x foaf:name ?name1. 
 }
 FILTER NOT EXISTS { 
     GRAPH <blabla2>
     {   
       ?l swrc:author ?x.
     }
  }
```

}

Note that using this approach you can actually get rid of variable `?y` altogether: you change the condition to just check that author `?x` as found in the first graph does not also occur in the second graph.