# Strange SPARQL behavior using variables vs. IRI

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, allegrograph

I'm facing a strange behavior using Allegrograph 4.13

This is the data for test case

```
prefix : <http://example.com/example#> 

INSERT DATA {
:A rdfs:label "A" .
:A :hasProp :Prop1 .
:Prop1 :Key "1" .
:Prop1 :Value "AA" .

:B :hasProp :Prop2 .
:Prop2 :Key "1" .
:Prop2 :Value "AA" .

:C :hasProp :Prop3 .
:C :hasProp :Prop4 .
:Prop3 :Key "1" .
:Prop3 :Value "AA" .

:Prop4 :Key "2" .
:Prop4 :Value "BB" .
}
```

Given :A, I need to find resources that have exactly the same properties.
That is, I want to find :B but not :C, because :C has one property more (Key "2" and Value "BB")

See also this question [Find individuals in SPARQL based on other relations / Compare sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24713925/find-individuals-in-sparql-based-on-other-relations-compare-sets)

The following query kindly provided by [Joshua Taylor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1281433/joshua-taylor) uses resource directly (:A) and does exactly what I want:

```
prefix : <http://example.com/example#> 

select ?other ?k ?v {
   :A    :hasProp [ :Key ?k ; :Value ?v ] .
   ?other :hasProp [ :Key ?k ; :Value ?v ] .
   filter not exists { 
     { :A :hasProp [ :Key ?kk ; :Value ?vv ] .
       filter not exists { ?other :hasProp [ :Key ?kk ; :Value ?vv ] .
       }
     }
     union
     {
      ?other :hasProp [ :Key ?kk ; :Value ?vv ] .
      filter not exists { :A :hasProp [ :Key ?kk ; :Value ?vv ] .
      }
   }
  }
 }
```

Answer:

```
 -------------------  
 |other|  k  | v  
 |A    | "1" | "AA"  
 |B    | "1" | "AA"  
 -------------------
```

The second one is using a variable ?a, because I need to find :A first according to some criteria (rdfs:label in this example)

Query using variable ?a:

```
 prefix : <http://example.com/example#> 

select ?other ?k ?v {
   ?a rdfs:label "A" .
   ?a    :hasProp [ :Key ?k ; :Value ?v ] .
   ?other :hasProp [ :Key ?k ; :Value ?v ] .
   filter not exists { 
     { ?a :hasProp [ :Key ?kk ; :Value ?vv ] .
       filter not exists { ?other :hasProp [ :Key ?kk ; :Value ?vv ] .
       }
     }
     union
     {
      ?other :hasProp [ :Key ?kk ; :Value ?vv ] .
      filter not exists { ?a :hasProp [ :Key ?kk ; :Value ?vv ] .
      }
    }
   }
 }
```

returns

```
 -------------------  
 |other|  k  | v  
 |A    | "1" | "AA"  
 |B    | "1" | "AA"  
 |C    | "1" | "AA"  
 -------------------
```

This query returns also :C which is wrong in my opinion.

Can anybody explain this behavior or verify this test case with other triple stores / SPARQL engines ?

---

### Additional Tests

As per request in the comments, I added the prefix for rdfs and also substituted the blank nodes with variables. This seems to have no effect.

```
prefix : <http://example.com/example#> 
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select ?a ?pr1 ?pr2 ?other ?k ?v {
  ?a rdfs:label "A" .
  # bind (:A as ?a) .
  ?a    :hasProp ?pr1 .
  ?pr1 :Key ?k ; :Value ?v .
  ?other :hasProp ?pr2 .
  ?pr2 :Key ?k ; :Value ?v .

 filter not exists { 
   { ?a :hasProp ?pp1 .
     ?pp1 :Key ?kk ; :Value ?vv  .
  filter not exists { ?other :hasProp ?pp2 .
                     ?pp2 :Key ?kk ; :Value ?vv .
  }
}
union
{
 ?other :hasProp ?pp3 .
  ?pp3 :Key ?kk ; :Value ?vv .
 filter not exists { ?a :hasProp ?pp4 .
                    ?pp4 :Key ?kk ; :Value ?vv .
 }
 }
 }  
 }
```

```
a    pr1     pr2   other k       v  
A   Prop1   Prop1   A   "1"     "AA"  
A   Prop1   Prop2   B   "1"     "AA"  
A   Prop1   Prop3   C   "1"     "AA"
```

If I use BIND (commented) instead of the line with rdfs:label it looks the same.

Comment: Do the queries you have here run as is?  I.e., is Allegro automatically inserting the definition for **rdfs:**?

Comment: What happens if you replace the blank nodes in the query with some variables?  E.g., if you do `?a rdfs:label "A". ?a :hasProp ?aprop . ?aprop :Key ?k ; ?Value ?v` and similarly with an `?otherprop`?  I wonder what resources those are getting matched against.

Comment: I added the content from your answer to the question (the answer got deleted, because it's not an answer, but it was useful information).  If you're not fed up with this yet, can you try another test?  What if instead of `filter not exists { {…} union {…} }` you use `filter not exists {…} filter not exists {…}`?

Comment: I tried it but nothing has changed.

Comment: Did you make any progress with this?

Comment: I submitted a bug report, but have no response yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you've found a bug in AllegroGraph.  It seems like adding the **?a rdfs:label "A"** should restrict the value of **?a** to being **:A**, and that's the behavior we see with Jena.

```
Jena:       VERSION: 2.11.0
Jena:       BUILD_DATE: 2013-09-12T10:49:49+0100
ARQ:        VERSION: 2.11.0
ARQ:        BUILD_DATE: 2013-09-12T10:49:49+0100
RIOT:       VERSION: 2.11.0
RIOT:       BUILD_DATE: 2013-09-12T10:49:49+0100
```

```sql
prefix : <http://example.com/example#> 
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select ?other ?k ?v {
   ?a rdfs:label "A" .
   ?a    :hasProp [ :Key ?k ; :Value ?v ] .
   ?other :hasProp [ :Key ?k ; :Value ?v ] .
   filter not exists { 
     { ?a :hasProp [ :Key ?kk ; :Value ?vv ] .
       filter not exists { ?other :hasProp [ :Key ?kk ; :Value ?vv ] .
       }
     }
     union
     {
      ?other :hasProp [ :Key ?kk ; :Value ?vv ] .
      filter not exists { ?a :hasProp [ :Key ?kk ; :Value ?vv ] .
      }
   }
  }
 }
```

```
----------------------
| other | k   | v    |
======================
| :B    | "1" | "AA" |
| :A    | "1" | "AA" |
----------------------
```

It probably makes sense to come up with the minimal example that reproduces this behavior, and to submit a bug report.